# Sudo email notification setup error

Tags: sudo, sudoedit

I'm Using Centos version:

```
[sysadmin@backup-srv ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

I'm using this sudo version:

```
[sysadmin@backup-srv ~]$ sudo -V
Sudo version 1.8.6p3
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.6p3
Sudoers file grammar version 42
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.6p3
```

I tried to setup notification mail for sudo, added this entry in bottom of sudo file using command visudo, but I am getting the following syntax error:

```
Defaults    mailto "babin@xxxxxxxxx.com"
Defaults    mailfrom "root@media.xxxxxxxxxxx.com
Defaults    mail_always on
Defaults    mailsub “*** Command run via sudo on %h ***”
Defaults    mail_badpass on
Defaults    badpass_message "Please Provide Correct Password"
Defaults    !lecture,tty_tickets,!fqdn,!syslog
Defaults    logfile=/var/log/sudo.log
```

This is the error I get while saving the sudo config file:

```
 121 Defaults        mailto "babin@xxxxxxxxx.com"
 122 Defaults        mailfrom "root@media.xxxxxxxxxxx.com
 123 Defaults        mail_always on
 124 Defaults        mailsub “*** Command run via sudo on %h ***”
 125 Defaults        mail_badpass on
 126 Defaults        badpass_message "Please Provide Correct Password"
 127 Defaults        !lecture,tty_tickets,!fqdn,!syslog
 128 Defaults        logfile=/var/log/sudo.log
```

The error is:

```
visudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 121 <<<
visudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 121 <<<
```

What to do now? How to setup the mail notification for Sudo version 1.8.6p3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in your line 121, but in your next line, with your line `mailfrom "root@media.xxxxxxxxxxx.com`. You forgot the closing double apostrophe. The good version were:

```
mailfrom "root@media.xxxxxxxxxxx.com"
```

The ground, why it was as a syntax error in line 121, and not in 122, is because the syntax analyser of the sudo and your text editor used a little bit different line ordering.

Comment: ok its corrected but still i cant get mail while executing sudo

Comment: @Lonston Then it is another problem - I suggest to ask this as a new question, maybe you get good answers. It is probably a local mail delivery problem and has nothing with sudo to do. If you make 2 different questions to solve the same problem, it is normally not a problem here (at least if they aren't duplicates, but in this case they aren't). And yet another suggestion: use the "shift", ".", "," characters are they are intended to, their rules are very simple but they make your text look _much_ better.

Comment: Can you send mails from the command line with the mail command? (f.e. with the command `echo "test mail"|mail root@media.xxxx.com`)

Comment: yes i can send mail from command line and i have received to my personal email id from VPS

Comment: @Lonston It is really another problem, please make a new question. This question was about the syntax problem in your sudoers file, this was fixed - I really can't do anything with it that there is another problem in your system as well. But this problem can be just so simple fixed as this was.

Comment: {Defaults        mailto = "babin@xxxxxxxxx.com"
Defaults        mailfrom = "root@xxxxxxxxx.in"
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        mail_always
Defaults        mailsub = "*** Command run via sudo on %h ***"
Defaults        badpass_message = "Please Provide Correct Password"
Defaults        !lecture,tty_tickets,!fqdn,!syslog
Defaults        logfile=/var/log/sudo.log} 

its worked for me

Comment: @Lonston Ask this in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a similar Error, without the missing double quote, with the same version of sudo -- **1.8.6p3** on **centos 6.5**.

It looks like visudo wanted the equals syntax --

```
Defaults mailto = "xxx@xx.com"
Defaults mail_always
```

Specifying

```
Defaults mailto "xxx@xx.com"
Defaults mail_always on
```

Resulted in a syntax error for both entries.